# How can I investigate the convergence of this series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} + \ \frac{1}{\sqrt 7} - \frac{1}{\sqrt 4} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 9} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{11}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt 6} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}+\ldots$$

My opinion (just an opinion - no idea what I'm doing here):

let this be the series $\sum a_n b_n$ where $b_n$ follows the pattern $+1,+1,-1,+1,+1,-1,\ldots$

Clearly the series of $b_n$ doesn't have bounded partial sums - so I can not apply the alternating series test. But not being able to apply the alternating series test wouldn't imply it's to be divergent. Any hints?

Comment: How comes that you have never any idea of even the basics of the subjects your questions are about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{4k+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4k+3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+2}}\right) $$
**is not** conditionally convergent since its general term behaves like $\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ for moderately large values of $k$, and $\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right\}_{k\geq 1}$ **is not** a summable sequence. On the other hand
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} = (1-\sqrt{2})\,\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \approx 0.60489864342163$$
so your problem is an instance of the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) (we may rearrange the terms of the previous series and make it divergent!)